# C3861 compiler error in a sample C++ project using Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am a recent C++ student trying to understand functions, and keep receiving a C3861 error when building my program. The project has a lot of criteria, but the main one is using each of these functions. I declared or prototyped the functions before int main(), but still get the errors. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
// Project 5 for COP2000
// This program will read a text document with nine employee IDs, rates, hours, and will display the calculated payroll to the user.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void openFile();
void testFile();
double readFile(int employeeID, double employeeRATE, double employeeWeeklyHours, double employeePAY, int counter);
double calcWeeklyPay(int employeeID, double employeeRATE, double employeeWeeklyHours, double employeePAY);
void displayEmployee(int employeeID, double employeePAY);
void closeFile();
void displayTable(double grossPAYROLL, double employeePAY1, double employeePAY2, double employeePAY3, double employeePAY4, double employeePAY5, double employeePAY6, double employeePAY7, double employeePAY8, double employeePAY9);


int main()
{

    int employeeID{};
    double employeeRATE{}, employeeWeeklyHours{}, employeePAY{};
    double employeePAY1, employeePAY2, employeePAY3, employeePAY4, employeePAY5, employeePAY6, employeePAY7, employeePAY8, employeePAY9;
    double grossPAYROLL{};

    int counter = 0;

    openFile();

    testFile();

    employeePAY1 = readFile(employeeID, employeeRATE, employeeWeeklyHours, employeePAY, counter);
    counter++;
    employeePAY2 = readFile(employeeID, employeeRATE, employeeWeeklyHours, employeePAY, counter);
    counter++;
    employeePAY3 = readFile(employeeID, employeeRATE, employeeWeeklyHours, employeePAY, counter);
    counter++;
    employeePAY4 = readFile(employeeID, employeeRATE, employeeWeeklyHours, employeePAY, counter);
    counter++;
    employeePAY5 = readFile(employeeID, employeeRATE, employeeWeeklyHours, employeePAY, counter);
    counter++;
    employeePAY6 = readFile(employeeID, employeeRATE, employeeWeeklyHours, employeePAY, counter);
    counter++;
    employeePAY7 = readFile(employeeID, employeeRATE, employeeWeeklyHours, employeePAY, counter);
    counter++;
    employeePAY8 = readFile(employeeID, employeeRATE, employeeWeeklyHours, employeePAY, counter);
    counter++;
    employeePAY9 = readFile(employeeID, employeeRATE, employeeWeeklyHours, employeePAY, counter);

    closeFile();

    displayTable(grossPAYROLL, employeePAY1, employeePAY2, employeePAY3, employeePAY4, employeePAY5, employeePAY6, employeePAY7, employeePAY8, employeePAY9);





}

//***************************************//
// openFile()                            //
//***************************************//


void openFile()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("C:\\Users\\Maxwell Reinhard\\Downloads\\weeklyMar9.txt");

    return;

}


//***************************************//
// testFile()                            //
//***************************************//


void testFile()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    if (inputFile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File has been successfully opened";
        inputFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error opening file";
    }


    return;



}


//***************************************//
// readFile()                            //
//***************************************//


double readFile(int employeeID, double employeeRATE, double employeeWeeklyHours, double employeePAY, int counter)
{
    ifstream inputFile;

    inputFile.ignore(counter, '\n');

    while (inputFile >> employeeID >> employeeRATE >> employeeWeeklyHours)
    {
        employeePAY = calcWeeklyPay(employeeID, employeeRATE, employeeWeeklyHours, employeePAY);



    }


    displayEmployee(employeeID, employeePAY);

    return employeePAY;
}


//***************************************//
// calcWeeklyPay()                       //
//***************************************//


double calcWeeklyPay(int employeeID, double employeeRATE, double employeeWeeklyHours, double employeePAY)
{
    if (employeeWeeklyHours <= 40)
    {
        employeePAY = (employeeWeeklyHours * employeeRATE);
    }
    else
    {
        employeePAY = (((employeeWeeklyHours - 40) * (employeeRATE * 1.5)) + (40 * employeeRATE));
    }

    return employeePAY;

}


//***************************************//
// displayEmployee()                     //
//***************************************//


void displayEmployee(int employeeID, double employeePAY)
{
    cout << employeeID << "'s weekly pay is: " << employeePAY << '\n';

    return;
}


//***************************************//
// closeFile()                           //
//***************************************//


void closeFile()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.close();

    return;
}


//***************************************//
// displayTable()                        //
//***************************************//


void displayTable(double grossPAYROLL, double employeePAY1, double employeePAY2, double employeePAY3, double employeePAY4, double employeePAY5, double employeePAY6, double employeePAY7, double employeePAY8, double employeePAY9)
{
    grossPAYROLL = employeePAY1 + employeePAY2 + employeePAY3 + employeePAY4 + employeePAY5 + employeePAY6 + employeePAY7 + employeePAY8 + employeePAY9;

    cout << "The total payroll for this week is: " << grossPAYROLL << '\n';

    return;


}
```

Errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3861   'testFile': identifier not found    Project5    C:\Users\Maxwell Reinhard\source\repos\Project5\Project5\Source1.cpp    24  
Error   C3861   'readFile': identifier not found    Project5    C:\Users\Maxwell Reinhard\source\repos\Project5\Project5\Source1.cpp    26  
Error   C3861   'readFile': identifier not found    Project5    C:\Users\Maxwell Reinhard\source\repos\Project5\Project5\Source1.cpp    28  
Error   C3861   'readFile': identifier not found    Project5    C:\Users\Maxwell Reinhard\source\repos\Project5\Project5\Source1.cpp    30  
Error   C3861   'readFile': identifier not found    Project5    C:\Users\Maxwell Reinhard\source\repos\Project5\Project5\Source1.cpp    32  
Error   C3861   'readFile': identifier not found    Project5    C:\Users\Maxwell Reinhard\source\repos\Project5\Project5\Source1.cpp    34  
Error   C3861   'readFile': identifier not found    Project5    C:\Users\Maxwell Reinhard\source\repos\Project5\Project5\Source1.cpp    36  
Error   C3861   'readFile': identifier not found    Project5    C:\Users\Maxwell Reinhard\source\repos\Project5\Project5\Source1.cpp    38  
Error   C3861   'readFile': identifier not found    Project5    C:\Users\Maxwell Reinhard\source\repos\Project5\Project5\Source1.cpp    40  
Error   C3861   'readFile': identifier not found    Project5    C:\Users\Maxwell Reinhard\source\repos\Project5\Project5\Source1.cpp    42  
Error   C3861   'openFile': identifier not found    Project5    C:\Users\Maxwell Reinhard\source\repos\Project5\Project5\Source1.cpp    22  
Error   C3861   'displayTable': identifier not found    Project5    C:\Users\Maxwell Reinhard\source\repos\Project5\Project5\Source1.cpp    46  
Error   C3861   'displayEmployee': identifier not found Project5    C:\Users\Maxwell Reinhard\source\repos\Project5\Project5\Source1.cpp    115 
Error   C3861   'closeFile': identifier not found   Project5    C:\Users\Maxwell Reinhard\source\repos\Project5\Project5\Source1.cpp    44  
Error   C3861   'calcWeeklyPay': identifier not found   Project5    C:\Users\Maxwell Reinhard\source\repos\Project5\Project5\Source1.cpp    108
```

Comment: When asking questions about build errors, always please include a full and complete copy-paste (as text) of the errors, and add comments in the example where you get the errors. Also please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And lastly please don't forget the *minimal* mart of your [mcve].

Comment: The code you show [compiles as written](https://rextester.com/FTNB11422). To the extent there is a problem, it must needs lie in the code not shown.

Comment: In the code you've shown, `testFile` is on line 29, not line 24.  Did you edit `Source1.cpp` and not save the changes before compiling?